# Java split function not woring in j2me

Tags: java, java-me

I am trying to take string in a textbox and then split the text from the text box and display it on another form but i am not able to achieve it as everytime i put split function it shows me an error
Here's the code

```
if (c == next) {
  String str = tb.getString();
  String[] st = str.split(":|;")
  System.out.println(st);

  f1.append(str);

  display.setCurrent(f1);
}
```

Comment: Can you share the error?

Comment: `everytime i put split function it shows me an error` which error? please paste the stacktrace in the question

Comment: I'm assuming it's not simply the missing `;` on the end of the line...?

Comment: You aren't printing the array correctly. Try `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(st));`

Answer (score 2):

Split method is not supported in J2ME.

Answer (score 1):

you have missed the **`;`**

```
if (c == next) {
  String str = tb.getString();
  String[] st = str.split(":|;");
  System.out.println(st);

  f1.append(str);

  display.setCurrent(f1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Splits a string into multiple strings
 *
 * @param separator Separator char
 * @param source_string Source string
 * @return Array of strings
 *
 * source :
 * http://www.particle.kth.se/~lindsey/JavaCourse/Book/Code/P3/Chapter24/SNAP/Worker.java
 */
public static String[] split(char separator, String source_string) {

    // First get rid of whitespace at start and end of the string
    String string = source_string.trim();
    // If string contains no tokens, return a zero length array.
    if (string.length() == 0) {
        return (new String[0]);
    }

    // Use a Vector to collect the unknown number of tokens.
    Vector token_vector = new Vector();
    String token;
    int index_a = 0;
    int index_b;

    // Then scan through the string for the tokens.
    while (true) {
        index_b = string.indexOf(separator, index_a);
        if (index_b == -1) {
            token = string.substring(index_a);
            token_vector.addElement(token);
            break;
        }
        token = string.substring(index_a, index_b);
        token_vector.addElement(token);
        index_a = index_b + 1;
    }

    return toStringArray(token_vector);

} // split

/**
 * Convert a vector to an array of string
 *
 * @param vector Vector of string
 * @return Array of string
 */
public static String[] toStringArray(Vector vector) {
    String[] strArray = new String[vector.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < strArray.length; i++) {
        strArray[i] = (String) (vector.elementAt(i));
    }
    return strArray;
}
```